# how to get a value from a list in angularjs inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, onsen-ui

I am newbie to angularjs and have made a demo of list using onsen ui,i succeed in that,but now i want to get value associated to particular listitem when its clicked,the list hase items of radio buttons,I have tried but it gives me only first value.can anyone help me to get it?pls
**html**

```
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="area in AreaList">
          <label class="checkbox checkbox--list-item" >
              <input type="radio" ng-bind="area.name"  ng-model="area.code" name="area" value="{{area.code}}">
            <div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark"></div>
            {{area.name}}
          </label>
        </ons-list-item>
```

**js**

```
 $scope.AreaList = [];   
  //PARING FOR AREA
            if(data.Details[i] === "Area"){
                     for(var d=0;d<17;d++){

                         var area =data.Details[i+1][d]['varCityName'];
                         var code = data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode'];

                             $scope.AreaList.push({name:area, code:code});

                             area = '';
                             code = '';

                }


                console.log("===========AREA obj===========", areaobj);

   }
```

**area object printed in console.long**

```
[
    Object{
        name="Camana Bay",
        code="32"
    },
    Object{
        name="Breakers",
        code="1"
    },
    Object{
        name="Grand Cayman",
        code="2"
    },
    Object{
        name="Bodden Town",
        code="16"
    },
    Object{
        name="Cayman Brac",
        code="15"
    },
    Object{
        name="East End",
        code="20"
    },
    Object{
        name="George Town",
        code="21"
    },
    Object{
        name="George Town West",
        code="22"
    },
    Object{
        name="Little Cayman",
        code="23"
    }
   ]
```

Comment: You shouldn't be dealing with DOM elements in your controller. "Massage" the data that comes from the server to adapt it to your view's need, then place your HTML into templates making use of `ngShow`, `ngRepeat` to do the DOM transformation for you.

Comment: @ThiagoPXP-Thanks bro,but is there any chance that i get changed value at last?pls save me..thanks

Comment: Your code is a bit hard to follow, if you were doing the way Angular tells you to do: using `$scope` as the "glue" between the controller and the view, Angular would use its `$digest()` cycles to update values for you. Therefore, it would be easier to find out why your values are not been updated.

Comment: @ThiagoPXP-ok i will change myk controller and use ng-repeat as you told,but can you pls tell me how will i get selected value? from this [http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/yk8phbc5/] pls

Comment: @ThiagoPXP-i am using as per you told,now sir pls tell me how to get selected "code" from the list,pls,,see my edit..thanks you in advance..you helped me ..

Answer (score 0):

The selected value should be stored in another variable

```
$scope.selectedValue = null;
```

then you bind each `radio` to update this model.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in todoList">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedValue" name="area" value="{{x.name}}">
</div>
```

Comment: hello thank you for reply sir,I have edited my question,can you pls tell me how tog et a selected value from list of radio buttons.see my edit pls.

Comment: it gives me only last value..:( i dont know what is happening